# How to fix this error Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, aar, flutter-test

When i tried to run the app I'm getting this error Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle'.
how to rectify this?

Comment: can you share the error log?

Comment: As @towhid mentioned, post more details about code and error message.

To check flutter installation status run `flutter doctor` .
If everything has check marks then run `flutter clean` and then to resolve dependencies use `flutter pub get` .

Answer (score 10):

I just changed the **compileSdkVersion** to **29** instead of 28.

Comment: what is the reason, can you explain if you know?

Answer (score 10):

in androidmanifest.xml my *user-permission* was in wrong place and marked as red..
moved outside `<application>` and worked.

Answer (score 4):

Did you tried switching flutter channel to stable and then upgrade flutter version?
This worked for me.
run the following commands in cmd...

> flutter channel stable

then...

> flutter upgrade

Comment: I was in the beta channel for web development, so was getting the error while running an android app. Changing to stable channel fixed the issue. Thanks for the answer. Any idea how to fix it in beta channel?

Answer (score 1):

it happened to me before a few minutes in intelij idea, this error showed to me after updating gradle to 6.5.1 on android studio what i did is:
after updating gradle i've clicked **on Sync Project with Gradle Files** there is file on android studio called flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle i copied it and paste it inside a file called build on intelij idea after that i've uninistalled NDK (this can be found Setting-> Appearance & behavior -> Android SDK -> SDK tools finally i've changed **compileSdkVersion** to 28 this can be found inside a file called build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with this help

If you set 'org.gradle.configureondemand=true' in 'gradle.properties'，please change to false.
It wil be worked !

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter same issue, I have changed launch_background.xml to use splash screen with attached logo,
But forget to change the logo_name

**Below code (Error Exist)**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

<!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
</item>
```

Rather "launch_image" should change to my "logo name"